# Is there any way to open a website with specified cookies in a browser using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is there any way I can use Powershell to open a website in a browser with the cookies specified?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by preparing a [`WebRequestSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.webrequestsession) instance for use with the [`Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest):

```bsh
$uri = "https://some.website.example/path/page"

$session = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]::new()
$session.Cookies.Add($uri, [System.Net.Cookie]::new("CookieName", "Value"))

Invoke-WebRequest $uri -WebSession $session
```

Comment: You must have got it wrong. What I actually want is to open a page in a **browser**, As far as i now, Invoke-WebRequest doesn't do that. Anyway, thanks for your answer!